# Tips for how to code a very complicated custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

[image]

Please see my mockup pictured above.  I am a bit puzzled as how to code this.  I guess I would use one UITableView and have all customizations on one cell.  Any other ideas?  I wasn't sure if it would be better to have multiple tableviews on one controller or something instead.

Comment: Maybe you need `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: Was thinking that too... would it be one collection view with multiple cells? @Koen

Comment: Use a custom `UITableViewCell` created with a xib.

Answer (score 2):

First off, this design really won't work except on iPad. It's just too much to try to cram onto an iPhone screen.

Collection views are like a more flexible form of table view. You can arrange collection views in rows, columns, rows AND columns, circles, or whatever you want.

You can make a collection view act like a table view, but it's more work, and a little more confusing.

If your UI is a vertical list of cells, a table view might still be a better fit, since it matches what you're doing.

Assuming this app is iPad only:

Create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, with it's own XIB file. Define the contents as desired. Making each "tile" (the 5 boxes shown in each cell) in the table view cell a separate custom subclass of UIView might make sense, or it might not, depending on how you expect to use them. If they are always in the same order, and never used anywhere else but in this table view, then no. Just build the cell from components. If you ever think you might use one of these tiles somewhere else, or if you might ever display them in a different order, then yes, make each tile a separate custom UIView subclass, and use those custom views in constructing your cell.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple `UITableView` is bad idea – when you scroll one of them others will remain static. I would recommend you to use one table view but decouple a cell in the separate views (or even view controllers) and have a special view (maybe with .xib) for each of 5 components.

Comment: So are you saying on my prototype cell I'd have 5 UIViews laid on top? Thanks!

Comment: Not UIView's – I would recommend to create 5 custom UIView subclasses for each of your component and use them in your table cell